# D debugger (both Mago and cv2pdb) won't step into catch clauses

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, d, visual-d

I'm using D in Visual Studio 2013 with Visual-D. I'm unable to get either debugger to step into the catch clause of a try-catch statement, nor can I set a breakpoint in the catch clause. Is this expected behaviour and unsupported, or am I doing something crazy?